# Why using two variables in loop in R (code given below)?

Tags: r, loops

I am looking at DIGRE model code in R and there is a loop as follow:

```
idx <- 1
for (i in 1:length(drugName)) {
if (drugName[i] != "Neg_control") {
  cat(idx, ". ", drugName[i], "\n", sep = "")
  idx <- idx + 1
}
```

My question is a particular reason for using separate variables ( i and idx ) for loop and the counter. Wouldn't this loop work fine with just one variable. I am new to R therefore curious.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `idx` only gets incremented if `drugName` isn't `"Neg_control"`. So `i` indexes all the observations of `drugName` and idx counts the 'occurences'. I guess depending on how the data looks like and what the goal of the function is, this could be done without using a loop.

Comment: I think the reason for this code is to know at iteration `i` how many diferentes the loop have runned on. Another option is using `duplicated(drugName)` to calculate in another objetc the unique drugs names and the number of previous ones

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
controlTF = drugName != "Neg_control"

idx <- sum(controlTF)

paste0(1:idx, ". ", drugName[controlTF])
```